# Why can I use const with Array.slice() and still assign a new value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Just noticed that I initiated a const with `Array.slice()` and was still able to assign a value to it like this:

```
const clickTarget = e.target.innerHTML;
const newState = settings.slice();
const settingIndex = settings.indexOf(setting);

newState[settingIndex].setTo = clickTarget;

setSettings(newState);
```

Context: a click handler function.

Shouldn't there be an error that says you can't assign a new value with a constant?
I have a hunch this is due to slice only referencing an object within, and that it is therefor technically not yet assigned a value.

Comment: Try using let instead, maybe because `const` is immutable.

Answer (score 5):

Because `const` means that the reference to an object cannot change, it has no effect on what that object can do.

```
const arr = [];
arr.push(1); // This is allowed as you are modifying the object arr points to, not the reference pointer
arr = [...arr]; //this is an exception because you are trying to assign a new reference to the const arr
```

Answer (score 1):

Because const prevent you from assigning a new reference to your named variable, it doesn't make your variable immutable by preventing change in sub objects.

to prevent changes to an object use :

```
Object.freeze(newState)
```

This will make your object immutable preventing you from adding / deleting / modifying it properties